# Android: Border as gradient

Tags: android, gradient

How can I create a border (gradient from #color1 to transparent) around the activity using XML styles? Please see the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With plain XML this is not possible (as far as I know). But you can use the 9-patch images in order to do this. Just create one with the [Draw-9-patch tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) from the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with  and  tags as special drawables.
Take a look at [this example](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/07/19/android-shapes/).